# Can I deploy multiple ears or wars files in Webshpere portal only one time

Tags: ear, websphere-portal

I have more than 20 ears files and I take a lot of time to deploy each ear alone using Websphere portal, so I'm looking for a solution to deploy all ears only one time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try wsadmin scripting http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/trun_app_set_dragdrop.html

I never tried it, but it seems you can create special directory, copy ears into and all ears will be deployed automatically

Comment: this feature Global deployment Settings is not available for Websphere portal 7 :/

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere Portal has a packaging formate for many artefacts and it includes ear files as well. If you package your files based on the Portal Application Archive (PAA) definition you can use the Solution Installer to have them all installed in one shot and do more.

The ear file deployment would be simple by putting all ear files into a directory inside of the PAA named installableApps/ear. You need to follow some configuration steps but at the end you have a method to install and remove your full solution at once (or build multiple packages and install them as you want)

For reference the Infocenter link
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.5.0/config/si_paa_spec_compdir.dita